# Is Moreau-Yosida regularisation Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, regularization

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07850).
In the proof of theorem 2, the authors refer to the Lipschitzness of Moreau-Yosida regularisation with citation. Like this:

For convex function $f$, Moreau-Yosida regularisation $g_{\eta}$ is defined as follows,
$$
g_{\eta} = \inf_{y \in K} \left( \frac{1}{2 \eta} ||x-y ||^2 + f(y) \right)
$$
Then, $g_{\eta}$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $\frac{1}{2 \eta}$.

However, I cannot find such contents from the cited reference.
Is it true?

EDIT: I think it's false cuz a representative example of Moreau-Yosida regularisation is Huber function $g_{\eta}(x) = \frac{1}{2\eta} x^2$ if $|x| \leq \eta$; otherwise, $|x| - \frac{\eta}{2}$, for $f(x) = |x|$.

Then, Is it true that Moreau-Yosida regularisation is Lipschitz continuous (on a compact set)?

EDIT2: I think that on a compact set $X$, the regularisation provides Lipschitz continuous function. Note that the cited theorem of [the reference](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-06409-2), Thm. 4.1.4, says that the gradient $\nabla g_{\eta}$ of $g_{\eta}$ is $\frac{1}{\eta} (x - prox(x))$ where $prox(x)$ is the proximal point. Hence, if the function is defined on a compact set, subset of real space, then the Lipschitz constant of $g_{\eta}$ will be given as $\frac{1}{\eta} \text{diam}(X)$ where $\text{diam}(X)$ is diameter of bounded set $X$.